# Reuse ts models once build in R to updated data set (forecast package)

Tags: r, time-series, updates, reusability, forecasting

I am quite new to R programming but I cant find anything about my Problem...

I would like to do some forecasting in R with the forecasting package from high resolution data (halfhourly data).
I would like to have the forecast working online. That is why I think calculating a fit every single time is not very useful.

Therefore I like the method to pass the already fitted model to the Model and use it for new data:

```
fcast2 <- forecast ( Arima ( x = extendedSeries , model = oldArimaModel ), h = horizon )
```

But it does not really work with an HoltWinters model... 
(or a lm -model which is ok regarding what lm means)

```
fcastArima <- forecast(Arima(x= extendedseries , model=oldArimaFit),h=horizon)
fcastHoltWinters <- forecast(update(oldHWfit, x=extendedSereies), h=horizon)
```

anyway,  I would like to keep the code simple and I am looking for a more generic method to apply already fitted ts models to the updated data set.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Cheers

Comment: I just discoverd the dshw function in the R forecast package... any ideas how to deal with that aiming the same target as above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HoltWinters()` is a very limited function. The `ets()` function will fit the same models, with better estimation, and will fit a much larger range of similar models. It also allows re-fitting to new data in the same way you are doing with `Arima()`.

Comment: Thank you Dr. Hyndman for your quick answer. Is there a way to avoid the auto-surpression of frequencies higher than 24 in ets function (i got 48 values per day)? Cheers Basti

Comment: If you have high frequency data, use tbats() instead of ets().